# React Native - Set parent match width for component inside a ScrollView that is inside a Modal

Tags: react-native

I have a `Modal` with a `ScrollView` inside and some items inside the `ScrollView`. When the `Modal` popped up, the item's border is not aligned to the `Modal`'s border. Some components like `TextInput` become thinner and some is overflow. It's not like this outside of `Modal`.

This can be solved by setting component's offset explicitly relative to `Dimensions.get('window').width`. But I just want an implicit solution.

I've done trying setting style properties for `ScrollView`'s `contentContainerStyle` and also putting a wrapper `View` inside the `ScrollView`. None of them works.

Comment: can you show you code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it after wrap `ScrollView` with a `View` with style `flexDirection : 'row'`. Yet to figure out why